# Why is this creating a tuple?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, tuples

```
tablewid = spark.sql("select * from mscovchar.covenc")
winid = Window.partitionBy("personid").orderBy("encdate", 'personid')
tablewid = tablewid.withColumn("infectedpersonid",F.when(F.col('personid') != F.lag(F.col("personid")),1)),F.monotonically_increasing_id().over(winid)
tablewid.show()
```

I'm just trying to add a column to a dataframe that creates an id when personid does not equal the previous row's personid. Any thoughts as to why my withColumn is transforming the dataframe into a tuple? It does not make sense to me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `tablewid = tablewid.withColumn("infectedpersonid",F.when(F.col('personid') != F.lag(F.col("personid")),1)),F.monotonically_increasing_id().over(winid)` is not a valid python statement can be edit the question to reflect the code you are using.

Comment: It is _syntactically_ valid, however, this is the reason that you are getting tuple for `tablewid`. `withColumn`'s parentheses is closed before `,F.monotonically...` meaning you are returning result from `withColumn` AND `F.monotonically...` into `tablewid` as tuple.